# How to programmatically select a wxPython RadioButton

Tags: python, wxpython

How to programmatically select/check a wxPython RadioButton? Or put differently, how can I define the default selection in a radio button group?

```
baud_boxsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
baud_boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel, label="9600", style=wx.RB_GROUP))
baud_boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel, label="57600"))
...
```

The [RadioButton](https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.RadioButton-class.html) API doesn't seem to offer such a function and the radio button *group* is kind of "virtual" because it only exists in the GUI.

I know I could use a RadioBox but I don't know how to style it so it doesn't *look* like a RadioBox (just need a horizontal row of radio buttons).

Comment: A quick perusal of the web shows that [`SetValue`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.RadioButton.html#wx.RadioButton.SetValue) should be able to do it.

Comment: Works, thanks. I now learned that looking at the [wxPython Phoenix docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.RadioButton.html#wx.RadioButton.SetValue) is really useful - even it I'm not using the Phoenix version. The [2.8.x API](https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.RadioButton-class.html#SetValue) docs are absolutely useless in this regard. I'd also argue that "SetValue" is a terrible name for a method that checks/unchecks a GUI control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that there is a coded answer for future reference, rather than just a comment:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Frame", size=(600, 300))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        #self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,  self.OnMove)
        my_boxsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        my_apple = wx.RadioButton(self.panel, -1, "Apple")
        my_mango = wx.RadioButton(self.panel, -1, "Mango")
        my_banana = wx.RadioButton(self.panel, -1, "Banana")
        my_orange = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Orange", (20,250), (160,-1))
        my_boxsizer.Add(my_apple, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        my_boxsizer.Add(my_mango, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        my_boxsizer.Add(my_banana, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        my_boxsizer.Add(my_orange, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(my_boxsizer)
        my_banana.SetValue(True)
        my_orange.SetValue(True)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: We already established that this be the correct answer as you noted but thanks anyway. Accepted.